# How can I work out how these colour values are encoded?

Tags: character-encoding, ascii

I'm scripting addons for After Effects, and I want to use the values stored in a user's preference file that determine the colours of UI elements. The values are stored in a plain txt file and look like this when I view it in Notepad++

```
["Label Preference Color Section 5"]
"Label Color ID 2 # 1" = FFFF"33"
"Label Color ID 2 # 2" = FFE4D8"L"
"Label Color ID 2 # 3" = FFA9CBC7
"Label Color ID 2 # 4" = FFE5BCC9
"Label Color ID 2 # 5" = FFA9A9CA
"Label Color ID 2 # 6" = FFA896"w"
"Label Color ID 2 # 7" = FFFFFFFF …
```

If I go through the UI and look at the decoded values for those colours I get this:

```
#   pref       decoded value
_____________________
#1 FFFF"33"  → FF3333
#2 FFE4D8"L" → E4D84C
#3 FFA9CBC7  → A9CBC7
#4 FFE5BCC9  → E5BCC9
#5 FFA9A9CA  → A9A9CA
#6 FFA896"w" → A89677
#7 FFFFFFFF  → FFFFFF
```

So it's *this close* to ASCII encoded hex, but not quite.

EDIT
The quotes seem to contain values encoded as a hex string. I tried some other values to see how they were encoded, for example 345678 gets encoded as "4vx", which if you strip the quotes is the hex encoding of 345678, according to [dencode](https://dencode.com/?v=4Vx&oe=UTF-8&nl=crlf&tz=America%2FNew_York)

<strike>Could it be 7-bit ASCII? The program has been around for decades, and there's a lot of stuff that has been made backward compatible.</strike> If so, how do I decode it in JS?

Comment: 7bit ascii is the same as ascii. I would ask on a sister site (photo, or film) if somebody know how the things are encoded (it seems there is some logic, but better to find document). Tags are not optimal to attract relevant people (also in this site). Did you check API docs?

Comment: I'm the person most likely to be able to answer it on videoproduction.stackexchange.com and I'd say it's more of a programming question than a video question.

Comment: Also, documentation? You jest, surely. This is Adobe we're talking about.

Comment: I agree that the question is on topic here. But some geek on other sister sites often have more insides about the formats and plugins. (for photos, there are non-programmer which knows every details of xmp files, or of the sqlite database used by Lightroom). Lightroom has many plug-ins (often made by non-professionals), so I was expecting much documentation. But i never programmed Adobe plugins.

Comment: http://estk.aenhancers.com/ and http://docs.aenhancers.com/ are pretty compressive. You should check if there are already the right functions.